# Why am I getting a JSONDecodeError when trying to load a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to load a JSON file in to Python, but it's giving me an JSONDecodeError error which seems to suggest the file is empty... which I know is not true.

I've reviewed similar questions I can find on here (65466227 & 62286816), and while one or two provide useful alternatives... that's not really the point. I feel like what I'm doing *should* work but it doesn't.

I put my JSON in to jsonlint.com and it confirmed that my JSON is indeed valid.

Error message/traceback:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/fmt_test.py", line 62, in <module>
    test_cases_json = json.load(jf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My Python code:

```py
test_case_file, _ = os.path.splitext(fmt_file)
test_case_file = f"{test_case_file}.json"
if os.path.isfile(test_case_file):
    with open(test_case_file, "r") as jf:
        test_cases_json = json.load(jf)
```

My JSON:

```json
{
    "tests": [
        {
            "id": "746fd83s23dy",
            "event": "%t LFA_DUMMYSTRING LFA_DUMMYSTRING TEST LFA_DUMMYSTRING1 LFA_DUMMYSTRING2 TEST2 LFA_DUMMYSTRING",
            "match": "True"
        },
        {
            "id": "990gb98s34dm",
            "event": "%t LFA_DUMMYSTRING LFA_DUMMYSTRING1 LFA_DUMMYSTRING2",
            "match": "True"
        },
        {
            "id": "100ma09x31ui",
            "event": "%t localhost LFA_DUMMYSTRING1 LFA_DUMMYSTRING2 TEST3 LFA_DUMMYSTRING1 LFA_DUMMYSTRING2",
            "match": "True"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to specify file encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely a UTF-8 BOM encoded at the beginning of the file since it is complaining about the first byte.  Open with `encoding='utf-8-sig'` and it will be removed if present:

```py
>>> import json
>>> data = {}
>>> with open('test.json','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:  # write data with BOM
...   json.dump(data,f)
...
>>> with open('test.json') as f:  # read it back
...  data2 = json.load(f)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <traceback removed>
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)  # same error
>>> with open('test.json',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
...  data2 = json.load(f)
...
>>> # worked
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I added the encoding bit on but it still gives the same error. Can you elaborate on the json.dump bit? My program never writes any data to the file, it only ever reads it.

Comment: @SamWood I was just demonstrating that if the JSON file was generated with a BOM, it causes the error you see if opened without the encoding parameter. If you still get the error, you’ll need to use a hex editor on the file and see what the first character is that it is complaining about. Another encoding option could be `utf16`.  It writes a BOM as well, and JSON  won’t like it either